# HTML, CSS: how can I merge these divs in order to use float:left property on their children?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've 2 sets of thumbnails and in each set I'm displaying them one nearby each other in 4 columns using float:left.

I would like to "merge" the 2 sets (but I cannot change the html code) because I want the thumbnails of the second set floating right after the last thumbnail of the first set.

In other terms, if in the last row there are only 2 thumbnails and the last 2 columns are empty, the thumbnails of the second set should fill the empty columns of the last row of the first set.

This is the code...

```
<div class="field field-type-filefield field-field-image">
    <div class="field-items">
            <div class="field-item odd">
                    <a rel="lightbox[field_image][First image&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;/lancelmaat/content/stalkshow&quot; id=&quot;node_link_text&quot; class=&quot;active&quot;&gt;View Image Details&lt;/a&gt;]" href="http://localhost/lancelmaat/sites/default/files/files/projects/Stalkshow/images/LPrisPetjong.jpeg" class="lightbox-processed"><img width="89" height="89" title="" alt="First image" src="http://localhost/lancelmaat/sites/default/files/imagecache/galleryImage/files/projects/Stalkshow/images/LPrisPetjong.jpeg"></a>        </div>
              <div class="field-item even">
                    <a rel="lightbox[field_image][Second image&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;/lancelmaat/content/stalkshow&quot; id=&quot;node_link_text&quot; class=&quot;active&quot;&gt;View Image Details&lt;/a&gt;]" href="http://localhost/lancelmaat/sites/default/files/files/projects/Stalkshow/images/SeoulLEDScreen2a.jpeg" class="lightbox-processed"><img width="89" height="89" title="" alt="Second image" src="http://localhost/lancelmaat/sites/default/files/imagecache/galleryImage/files/projects/Stalkshow/images/SeoulLEDScreen2a.jpeg"></a>        </div>
              <div class="field-item odd">
                    <a rel="lightbox[field_image][Third image&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;/lancelmaat/content/stalkshow&quot; id=&quot;node_link_text&quot; class=&quot;active&quot;&gt;View Image Details&lt;/a&gt;]" href="http://localhost/lancelmaat/sites/default/files/files/projects/Stalkshow/images/SeoulSKT6.jpeg" class="lightbox-processed"><img width="89" height="89" title="" alt="Third image" src="http://localhost/lancelmaat/sites/default/files/imagecache/galleryImage/files/projects/Stalkshow/images/SeoulSKT6.jpeg"></a>        </div>

</div>


<!-- second set -->
<div class="field field-type-filefield field-field-video">
    <div class="field-items">
            <div class="field-item odd">
                    <a rel="lightbox[field_video][Video Number 1&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;/lancelmaat/content/stalkshow&quot; id=&quot;node_link_text&quot; class=&quot;active&quot;&gt;View Image Details&lt;/a&gt;]" href="http://localhost/lancelmaat/sites/default/files/files/projects/Stalkshow/videos/StalkSeoul8d1Mbps.flv" class="lightbox-processed"><img title="" alt="Video Number 1" src="http://localhost/lancelmaat/sites/default/files/imagecache/galleryVideo/files/projects/Stalkshow/videos/StalkSeoul8d1Mbps.flv"></a>        </div>
              <div class="field-item even">
                    <a rel="lightbox[field_video][Video Number 2&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;/lancelmaat/content/stalkshow&quot; id=&quot;node_link_text&quot; class=&quot;active&quot;&gt;View Image Details&lt;/a&gt;]" href="http://localhost/lancelmaat/sites/default/files/files/projects/Stalkshow/videos/stalkshowdvd21Mbps.flv" class="lightbox-processed"><img title="" alt="Video Number 2" src="http://localhost/lancelmaat/sites/default/files/imagecache/galleryVideo/files/projects/Stalkshow/videos/stalkshowdvd21Mbps.flv"></a>        </div>
              <div class="field-item odd">
                    <a rel="lightbox[field_video][Video Number 3&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;/lancelmaat/content/stalkshow&quot; id=&quot;node_link_text&quot; class=&quot;active&quot;&gt;View Image Details&lt;/a&gt;]" href="http://localhost/lancelmaat/sites/default/files/files/projects/Stalkshow/videos/StalkShowMoscow1Mbps.flv" class="lightbox-processed"><img title="" alt="Video Number 3" src="http://localhost/lancelmaat/sites/default/files/imagecache/galleryVideo/files/projects/Stalkshow/videos/StalkShowMoscow1Mbps.flv"></a>        </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

How can I merge these divs in order to use *float:left* property on their children ?

thanks

Comment: Without being able to alter the HTML (I assume it's from a CMS or another site), you can't accomplish this without Javascript since they're in different containing divs.

Comment: yeah exactly. they come from a CMS, ok. Anyway, how can I do it with javascript ? Should I use it to merge the 2 divs, or can I keep the html intact ? thanks

Comment: Even with JS, it's still not going to be easy or fun.

Comment: can you give me some directions ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? I don't fully understand but I'm thinking this might send you in the right direction...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Example - Thumbnails in 4 columns</title>
        <style>
<!--
.field-items {
    width:380px; /* 4 columns x 95px columns...
                    each column is an 89px thumbnail and 6px of border  */
}
.field-items a {
    float:left;
    text-decoration:none;
}
/* Just for demo purposes */
.set-1 img {
    border:3px solid red;
}
.set-2 img {
    border:3px solid green;
}
.set-3 img {
    border:3px solid blue;
}
-->
        </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="field field-type-filefield field-field-image set-1">
        <div class="field-items">
                <div class="field-item odd">
                        <a href="#" class="lightbox-processed"><img width="89" height="89" title="" alt="First image" src="http://richard.jp.leguen.ca/images/lenna.jpg"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="field-item even">
                        <a href="#" class="lightbox-processed"><img width="89" height="89" title="" alt="Second image" src="http://richard.jp.leguen.ca/images/lenna.jpg"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="field-item odd">
                        <a href="#" class="lightbox-processed"><img width="89" height="89" title="" alt="Third image" src="http://richard.jp.leguen.ca/images/lenna.jpg"></a>
                </div>
         </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <!-- second set -->
    <div class="field field-type-filefield field-field-video set-2">
        <div class="field-items">
                <div class="field-item odd">
                        <a href="#" class="lightbox-processed"><img title="" alt="Video Number 1" src="http://richard.jp.leguen.ca/images/lenna.jpg"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="field-item even">
                        <a href="#" class="lightbox-processed"><img title="" alt="Video Number 2" src="http://richard.jp.leguen.ca/images/lenna.jpg"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="field-item odd">
                        <a href="#" class="lightbox-processed"><img title="" alt="Video Number 3" src="http://richard.jp.leguen.ca/images/lenna.jpg"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="field-item even">
                        <a href="#" class="lightbox-processed"><img title="" alt="Video Number 2" src="http://richard.jp.leguen.ca/images/lenna.jpg"></a>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- third set -->
    <div class="field field-type-filefield field-field-video set-3">
        <div class="field-items">
                <div class="field-item odd">
                        <a href="#" class="lightbox-processed"><img title="" alt="Video Number 1" src="http://richard.jp.leguen.ca/images/lenna.jpg"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="field-item even">
                        <a href="#" class="lightbox-processed"><img title="" alt="Video Number 2" src="http://richard.jp.leguen.ca/images/lenna.jpg"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="field-item odd">
                        <a href="#" class="lightbox-processed"><img title="" alt="Video Number 3" src="http://richard.jp.leguen.ca/images/lenna.jpg"></a>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

In-browser you hey something like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [leguen.ca](https://richard.jp.leguen.ca/images/html-css-how-can-i-merge-these-divs-in-order-to-use-floatleft-property-on-thei.jpg))</sub>

This working, however, rests upon the assumption that all thumbnails will be 89px by 89px. Aditionally, you have to make sure that any element of class `field-items` does not have the CSS property `overflow-y:hidden`.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. The issue is that the parent divs have not the same number of thumbnails, so I cannot assume parent div = row. (if I understood well your code).

Comment: The issue here is that I need the children of the second parent to continue the float:left property effect of the children of the first parent div, in order to fill the empty cells on the last row of the previous parent div.

Comment: Have you looked at it in a browser? This still makes 4 columns if I change the number of items per row.

Comment: I'm sorry it looks like what I need.. I will implement it and let you know thanks

Comment: np. The catch is you need some kind of parent element (a `<div>` perhaps?) around all the 'rows', and you need to give that element an `overflow-y:hidden;` property, and it can't have a `height`.

Comment: ok it worked, I didn't know you can float elements even if they belong to different divs (!). Unluckily I cannot test it on IE yet, the website is offline. Is your solution cross-browser??

Comment: It should be, but I don't guarantee it ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to add properties to a selectors children use

```
.field-items *
{
    float: left;
}
```

The wildcard selector `*` will select all of the field-items class' children.  Now this may not be a final solution to the problem, but it's at least a start.

Comment: yeah, this is the starting point. The difficult point is how to merge the 2 divs.

Comment: If you remove the borders around everything, visually they will be merged.  if you want a border around both divs so that they appear merged, then that's just some fancy border footwork.  (top, right, bottom on one and top, left, bottom on the other)

Comment: this doesn't solve the issue, I guess. I copy paste here part of the question: "In other terms, if in the last row there are only 2 thumbnails and the last 2 columns are empty, the thumbnails of the second set should fill the 2 empty columns of the last row of the first set".. and not start a new row leaving the previous row empty.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to change them to `display:inline;` and see if that works, but honestly you're likely going to have to manually position them to fit together.  Why can't you change the html?

Comment: because my CMS (drupal) is grouping fields by groups (images and videos in this case). My customer needs to upload files from the back-end. But in the front-end these 2 fields should be merged.

Comment: Ahhh.... Wouldnt' it be more practical in the long run to change how Drupal presents the fields, rather than use CSS to fake it?  I'm running into a similar situation where I used some CSS to hide some structural faults in the html, and now that we want to make changes it's turning into a nightmare.